# Why the tasks cannot be started?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012

I have defined scheduled task like it in a windows 2012 server which is running in a Virtual Box. I can start these tasks with

```
schtasks /RUN /TN start-dop001
```

as a user 'dop001'. The task will start a python process.

[image]

However, when I replicate these settings in a Windows 2012 server in aws ec2 instance, the task cannot be started. There is no log or hint in event log.

All I can see is the output: `SUCCESS: Attempted to run the schedyled task "start-dop001"`

What would you suggest to investigate this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I, too, have an ec2 instance. And I, too, found Task Scheduler to not work.

Instead, do the following, **assuming you use Window's remote desktop tool to use the instance**:

1. Connect to your ec2 instance
2. Fullscreen the remote desktop window
3. Press WIN + R
4. Type **shell:startup** and press enter. A folder should open.
5. Create a shortcut to each of your files you want to run on startup and place the shortcuts in the folder you just opened
6. Restart the server to see if it works correctly.

**IF YOU DON'T USE WINDOW'S REMOTE DESKTOP TO USE THE EC2 INSTANCE, I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO HELP YOU**